# popping a new frame and deleting the old one in wxPython

Tags: wxpython

I have a simple frame with a button on it. What i want to do is when i press the button, i would like to close the frame and open a new one. The old one needs to be destroyed while the new one should have the same functionality as the destroyed frame. I want to do this an infinite time.

This is the code that i just wrote:

```
import wx


class subPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, value = 2):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.BtnPressHere = wx.Button(self, -1, "Press Here")
        self.value = value
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer()
        hbox.Add(self.BtnPressHere, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(hbox)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    class Screen(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, size = (600,600)) 
            panel = wx.Panel(self)
            panel0 = subPanel(panel, 0)
            box = wx.BoxSizer()
            box.Add(panel0, 1, wx.ALL |  wx.EXPAND)
            panel.SetSizer(box)
            self.Centre()
            self.Show(True)


    app = wx.App(False)
    Screen(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy to solve, look the code:

```
import wx

class ButtonFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, value):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None)

        self.BtnPressHere = wx.Button(self, -1, "Press Here: " + str(value))
        self.BtnPressHere.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnPress) # Need to bind the event
        self.value = value
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def OnPress(self,evt):
        ButtonFrame(self.value + 1)
        self.Destroy()  # Destroy this instance

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = wx.App(False)
    ButtonFrame(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

#### Remarks:

- If you put only a button on all frame area, the use of panel and sizers is unnecessary.
- The `self.Destroy()` call will destroy the window, after create another.

Comment: Thank you very much